# Keycloak Export only accept H2 datase-URL (Datasource: URL format error; must be jdbc:h2 ... but is jdbc:mariadb: ...)

Tags: docker, jdbc, docker-compose, mariadb, keycloak

Keycloak version: `20.0.1`

Docker version: `20.10.12`

Docker-Compose version: `2.2.2`

Github issues: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15898

#### The problem

I like to **export Keycloak-data from a MariaDB database**, but it's not possible.

The source I use is: https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport

The export command `export` **only accepts a H2 database-URL**, even I've created a build with proper database vendor. I've created a new build before execute the export: `build --db=mariadb`

There is an error displayed if I try to **export the Keycloak-data from the MariaDB database**.

The error is:

`Datasource '<default>': URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" but is "jdbc:mariadb://db.my-domain.de:3306/keycloak"`

#### Expected behavior

The expected behavior is , that the `export` command accept a MariaDB database-URL like `jdbc:mariadb:...`.

#### Actual behavior

The actual behavior is , that the `export` command only accept a H2 database-URL like `jdbc:h2:...` even if I execute `build --db=mariadb` before.

Also, the `show-config` commands shows that `kc.db =  mariadb (KcEnvVarConfigSource)` it isn't.

#### How to reproduce

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak-export:
      container_name: keycloak-export
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        KC_HOSTNAME: login.my-domain.com
        KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: true 
        KC_HTTP_ENABLED: false
        KC_PROXY: edge
        KC_DB: mariadb
        KC_DB_URL_HOST: db.my-domain.com
        KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
        KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
        KC_DB_USERNAME: ***
        KC_DB_PASSWORD: ***
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE: /keystore.p12
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: ***
      command:
        - export --dir /export_data
      volumes:
        - ./keystore.p12:/keystore.p12
        - ./export_data:/export_data
      restart: "no"
```

#### Additional information

In production mode, the Keycloak-Server connects to MariaDB-Database-Server based on this Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak:
      container_name: keycloak
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        KC_HOSTNAME: login.my-domain.de
        KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: true 
        KC_HTTP_ENABLED: false
        KC_PROXY: edge
        KC_DB: mariadb
        KC_DB_URL_HOST: db.my-domain.de
        KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
        KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
        KC_DB_USERNAME: ***
        KC_DB_PASSWORD: ***
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE: /keystore.p12
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: ***
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ***
        KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ***
        KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED: true
        KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
        KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      command:
        - start
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      volumes:
        - ./keystore.p12:/keystore.p12
      restart: always
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this in the end? I am running into similar issues exporting a MySQL database.

Comment: Still not solved @Campbell There is another user that also faced this issue. See the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15898 he provided also a (ugly) workaround

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to make similar progress by running the bare metal JDK version, as with the workaround on your GitHub issue I needed to first run the build command, and then the export one would work. Still no solution for exporting using Docker (other than creating my own image)

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the configuration first then export. So you should add "build" command.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak-export:
      container_name: keycloak-export
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        KC_HOSTNAME: login.my-domain.com
        KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: true 
        KC_HTTP_ENABLED: false
        KC_PROXY: edge
        KC_DB: mariadb
        KC_DB_URL_HOST: db.my-domain.com
        KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
        KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
        KC_DB_USERNAME: ***
        KC_DB_PASSWORD: ***
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE: /keystore.p12
        KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: ***
      command:
        - build && export --dir /export_data
      volumes:
        - ./keystore.p12:/keystore.p12
        - ./export_data:/export_data
      restart: "no"
```

Comment: This error message is thrown: `keycloak-export | Unknown option: 'export'
keycloak-export | Try 'kc.sh build --help' for more information on the available options.
keycloak-export exited with code 2` - are multiple commands in general possible?

Comment: I just changed the command can you retry it with the new one?

Comment: The container executes the build but but then the container hangs and stalls. Output is: ```keycloak-export  | Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
keycloak-export  | 2022-12-16 10:07:29,854 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 18766ms
keycloak-export  | Server configuration updated and persisted. Run the following command to review the configuration:
keycloak-export  |
keycloak-export  |      kc.sh show-config
keycloak-export  |
```

See that image: https://imgur.com/PsxieqT

Comment: @KevinO. The Keycloak entrypoint script processes the command line arguments. It gets confused when `build` and `export` are in the same invocation. Try to run `build` and `export` (with arguments) separately.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with MySQL, with the following :

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "33006:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE : keycloak
      MYSQL_USER : keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD : xyx
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asd
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1
    hostname: keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_DB: mysql
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: mysql
      KC_DB_URL_PROPERTIES : '?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true'
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: 'xyx'
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: false
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command:
      - start
```

Notes: If you use optimized with start, build first. Otherwise it goes with the embedded H2 db.
[Configuring the database - Keycloak 248](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db#:%7E:text=Do%20NOT%20use,Configuring%20Keycloak)

Refs:

- https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-17-run-in-docker-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy/13862

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the topic. This thread is about exporting and not running Keycloak.

Comment: yup! my bad, I was facing some issues trying to run keycloak and MySQL on docker compose and was facing the same exception, so through this would help